# Replace all instances of a character from a non-DOM string

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I need to take all plus symbols from a variable and replace them with spaces. I have tried:

```
someVariable = "0+123+45+6";
someVariable.replace(/+/g, ' ');
```

But this doesn't work... what would be the correct syntax for this situation?

Comment: The console says: `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /+/: Nothing to repeat`. That should give you a clue ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `+` is a special char (one or more), so you need to escape it.

should be `/\+/g`

**EDIT**
the regular expression does not modify the string object itself. but returns the result.

```
someVariable = "0+123+45+6";
someVariable = someVariable.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
```

Comment: Seems to be the same result? http://jsfiddle.net/zLL4B/ The outcome I need is `"0 123 45 6"` in this example.

Comment: @Chris updated my answer corresponding to your second problem

Comment: My bad - I was just missing "someVariable = " on my second line... I think your first suggestion works. Thank you for your help. http://jsfiddle.net/zLL4B/1/